# HANA Eclipse - Project Explorer "No connection to database"

Tags: eclipse, hana

When I start the HANA on Eclipse and go to the **Perspective -> Development -> Project Explorer** (tab)

a) the Procedures, Functions created have a message of "***No connection to database***"

[image]

b) also the XS Project created gets this "**System xxx is not configured**"

Not sure, how can re-connect the XS Project or the Procedure to the Database, nor which is the impact of the "System xxx is not configured".

Any clue on this ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In the development perspective, you are browsing repository files. You could see code for objects that haven't been activated yet.
If you switch the tab on the left panel to "Systems", then you could navigate the catalog, and there you'll see all the active procedures and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Remi.

Right. But when creating Procedures in HANA I believe we have 2 ways (from HANA Development Perspective):
a) through SQL command `CREATE PROCEDURE`
b) through Repositories (Tab) -> File -> Create -> Other -> Stored Procedure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSKkf.png)

I believe when we create Procedures through b) that we can modify the Procedures without the need of dropping them and creating them again.

Is in this scenario I am facing the above **"No connection to Database"** message.

Thank you,